# getting all child nodes of element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file on which I am applying transformation to a specific element and then try to get the text() of all the child nodes ignoring same node

```
<xml>
    <xrefline>
              <query>eligible individual</query>
              in respect of a qualified dependant at any time means a person who at that time   
              <quote>
              <para> 
               <n>(a)</n> 
              <parap>resides with the qualified dependant,</parap>
             </para> 
              </quote>
       </xrefline>
     </xml>
```

My xslt template looks like this and I want to extract all the text() and preserve the query element

```
<xsl:template match="query" >
<xsl:apply-templates select="../text()|../node()[self::query]|../node()[not(self::query)]/text()" ></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

My desire output should be like this

```
     <xml>
         <xrefline>
              <query>eligible individual</query>
              in respect of a qualified dependant at any time means a person who at that time (a) resides with the qualified dependant,
         </xrefline>
     </xml>
```

I have to work it around the `template match="query"` and then go back to get the desire result.  With my above xslt I am getting text which is out side the element quote but not the text of sub childs of quote element... any help or hint will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xrefline//*[not(self::query)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

see http://xsltransform.net/948Fn5h.

Comment: Hi Martin, your answer is spot on but can't it be done while processing the single template as mentioned in question... if will wait before making changes to code, if anyone can help...

Comment: Also Martin is there a way we can put xrefline content in CDATA like this  <xrefline>
              <![CDATA[<query>eligible individual</query>
              in respect of a qualified dependant at any time means a person who at that time (a) resides with the qualified dependant,
         ]]></xrefline>

Comment: Martin, I have implemented the code using your logic and it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: Creating a CDATA section works for text only elements using the `cdata-section-elements="xrefline"` attribute on `xsl:output`. However if you need to have the markup of an element like the `query` element in the CDATA then you first need to serialize that node which is only possible with an extension in XSLT 2.0 http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/serialize or with XSLT 3.0 http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/fn/serialize. If you need help on that then I suggest you post a new question.